# Separately licensing source code and website content

Tags: license-recommendation, license, dual-license

I am fairly new to actual open source licensing, since I usually just add the Unlicense to all my Github repositories, just to have it completely permissive for everyone.

I recently started a small github pages webpage for me and my friends, as a sort of small writing project. We use the static webpage as a sort of hub, that everyone can access from anywhere and read the things others write.

I am struggling to find a license, that could cover this webpage though. We don't care about source code, but if possible would like that the stories written be under CC 4.0 (such that Source and author have to be named when shared).

The stories are just plainly added in a  Element in static html pages for the sake of easy adding from non tech savvy friends, which makes it part of the source code technically.

From my research here, I found that maybe dual licensing is the way to go here.

This is my current try on adding a license:

> MIT License / CC-BY 4.0 Dual License
>
> Copyright (c) 2021 (Name)
>
> MIT License:
>
> [MIT License text] (excluded for brevity)
>
> CC-BY 4.0 License
>
> Images and texts that are not directly associated with source code (this includes any written >stories, author introductions, maps, etc.) may be used under CC-BY 4.0 International.
>
> See full information at:
> https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/
> A Summary of the conditions of this license are as follows:
>
> [CC License Text]

Is it possible to completely uncopyright the source code, while keeping any non source content under CC-BY 4? I neither want nor need the copyright of any of the source code, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my research here, I found that maybe dual licensing is the way to go here.

No, dual-licensing will *not* have the desired effect. When you dual-license something, the *recipient* gets to choose which license they want to conform to, so I would be able to take a writing of you and re-publish it under the MIT license.

> Is it possible to completely uncopyright the source code, while keeping any non source content under CC-BY 4?

As long as you can clearly and unambiguously indicate which license applies to what, you can use different licenses for the content of your webpage and for the source code.

You could write your licensing as

> Content and the HTML code for the page structure are separately licensed.
> The content is licensed under the CC BY 4.0 license.
> The code for the page structure is licensed under the Unlicense.
>
> <license texts>