# How to license website articles under a different licence to source code

Tags: licensing, website

I'm making a personal website whose source code I intend to license under a permissive licence like Apache 2.0, for example, I might host the code on GitHub and use GitHub Pages to host the site. But on the site I'll include original articles/blog posts and music, some of which will by CC0, some CC BY-SA 4.0, and some all rights reserved.

I might in the future host the site elsewhere so I can keep some code private and have some parts of the website unlicensed, so keeping all rights reserved (for example if I make a browser game and host it on mysite.com/game).

What would be the best way to declare the licence clearly?

Comment: Could you read [this question and its answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/11742/458) and let us know either that it satisfies your question, or instead, which part(s) of your question remain unanswered?  Thank you!